# Bookshelf.js - After updating record, initial page load/query displays old record. After refresh data displays correctly

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

When I set a column to null using bookshelf, and redirect to the page which displays that data, the data displays the un-updated record, until I refresh. Here's the code:

```
        Table.where({id: req.param.id}).fetch()
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .then(function (results) {
            results.set('other_column', null);
            results.save();
            results.refresh();
            // Redirect to orders page
            res.redirect('/landing-page');
        });
```

The landing page query is this:

```
        Table.where({id: req.param.id}).fetch()
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        })
        .then(function (results) {
            data.results = results.attributes;
            res.render('display-page', data);
        });
```

Does anyone know how I can fetch the updated record, or let me know if I am updating a record incorrectly? Any help solving this issue would be much appreciated as I can't render a page with the old data after having user just updated it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing you saving data like synchronous code, so the save() may (and often will) happen **AFTER** the refresh(). Try changing that to:

```
    Table.where({id: req.param.id}).fetch()
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        return results
          .set('other_column', null)
          .save();
    })
    .then(function (results) {  // results should now include the saved data
        // Redirect to orders page
        res.redirect('/landing-page');
    });
```

Comment: Also `catch` should be the last handler in the promise chain.

Comment: Agreed @RhysvanderWaerden. Placing the catch() last makes the chain to look more like a sequential try{}catch(){}. But since `catch()` is equivalent to `then(null, function(e){...})` this is more a style thing.

Comment: that is incorrect. In your code example the `then` handlers will be called in the case of an error. The `results` parameter will take the return value of the previous handler, in this case `undefined` from `catch`. This is not a style issue, it will cause runtime errors.